# Why do non-unique group names in TestNG tests affect other test classes? Can I use the same group names in different test classes?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I have the same group names for the methods in 2 of my test classes in TestNG, e.g.:

@Test(description = "step 4", groups = "4", dependsOnGroups = "3")

However, when I run one of these tests, the other one gets automatically included in the temporary xml file and it runs, as well. I want to keep my group names relatively simple and don't want them to be unique. Is this possible or I should make them unique?

Comment: What do you use to run tests? How does generated testng.xml look like?

Comment: This is the temporary xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
      <class name="FV_Automation.Framework.CheckoutPagesProgressIndicatorGuestUserTest"/>
      <class name="FV_Automation.Framework.CheckoutPagesProgressIndicatorRegisteredUserTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups are used exactly for this purpose - to collect test methods from all packages/classes. If test method has `dependsOnGroups` param, all related test methods will be triggered from all classes. If you want to prioritize your tests use `priority` param for `@Test`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this works. It seems I got the groups wrong.